# How to build out more complex vectorized operations?

Tags: r, vector

I have a sublist of principal component rotation vectors computed by `prcomp`, where each list item is an `Nx2` array (i.e., two column vectors), for each class.

Using those vectors, I'd like to project some data similarly structured into a list of classes, each class item containing arrays with dimension `NxMxT`, where `T` is the number of trials.

My problem is, I can write simple vectorized functions with `apply` and its variants, but I'm having trouble generalizing this to apply that over each list.

Example data:

```
somedata <- list(array(rnorm(100),dim=c(5,4,5)),array(rnorm(100),dim=c(5,4,5)))
somevectors <- list(array(rnorm(10),dim=c(5,2)),array(rnorm(10),dim=c(5,2)))
```

Here is a simple example of the operation over each list element:

```
o.proj.1 <- apply(somedata[[1]],3,function(x){
    t(somevectors[[1]]) %*% x
  }) # returns an array where each projected trial is a column
```

I tried fitting this inside a call to `lapply()`, but didn't find much success:

```
lapply(somedata, y = somevectors, function(x,y){
  apply(x,3,function(z){
    t(y) %*% z
  })
})

Error in t(y) %*% z : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Basically my algorithm is to put the appropriate `apply` type (here `lapply`) around the more local function and remove the index that will be vectorized (here `[[]]`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the `*apply` family of functions, `mapply` is the one to use when you want to loop simultaneously over two or more objects. Try:

```
o.proj <- mapply(function(x,y){
  apply(x,3,function(z){
    t(y) %*% z
  })
}, somedata, somevectors, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I suppose you will want to use `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to return a list, otherwise `mapply` will attempt to simplify your output into an array, a little like `sapply` does.

Also know that you can use `Map` as a shortcut for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`.

Comment: So in an iterative context, with `mapply` both `x` and `y` are iterated over the same first dimension in both objects? i.e., `x` corresponds to `somedata[[n]]` and `y` corresponds to `somevectors[[n]]` at any point in the function call?